# How can I add collections to mongodb automatically based on date?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I want to develop a travel booking website using MEAN stack development. Ticket booking can be done one month prior to the travel date. Today (30th July) I can book tickets till 30th august. Tomorrow i should be able to book tickets for 31st august. How can I make this happen and how do I make mongodb to create a collection for upcoming days automatically ?

Comment: You surely mean documents in a collection not multiple collections, right?

Comment: yes documents in a collection

Comment: The question is too broad to answer. But I don't think your requirement is any different from simple Create/Edit/Update/Delete operation with some business logic (like one month check) on server side. There will be a `Booking` collection and for each booking you'll create a document. There'll be a `booking_date` field in it.